# How to install librtaudio6 on Ubuntu LTS 16.04.3

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, dependencies

My app which is built in Kubuntu 18.04.1 doesn't run in Ubuntu LTS 16.04.3 because it cannot find `librtaudio.so.6`.

If I do

```
sudo apt-get install librtaudio-dev
```

It says

> librtaudio-dev is already the newest version (4.1.1~ds0-4)

Is it impossible to install librtaudio6 on Ubuntu LTS 16.04.03?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the package [from *bionic*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=librtaudio.so.6) manually and install it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/rtaudio/librtaudio6_5.0.0~ds-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./librtaudio6_5.0.0~ds-2_amd64.deb
```

This will result in:

> ```
> $ dpkg -S librtaudio.so.6
> librtaudio6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtaudio.so.6
> librtaudio6:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtaudio.so.6.0.0
> ```

Note: usually this method is not recommended, but while using it you do not need to recompile/rewrite source code of your application.